# Write error log on crash in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I've been having problems building my game. I've built it successfully before, until I added the `LuaJava.dll` and `LuaJava.jar` files (so I can use Lua in my game).

Now, it just briefly opens with black screen and immediately closes. Even though it works just fine in Eclipse.

What I used to do before, was set my `jar` file in my assets and it would just work fine. But now, it refuses to work, and I have no idea what the error is.

Is there a function I can call to output the error into a log file?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "set my jar file in my assets"? Jar files need to be added to the build path and should not be loaded as an asset.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about writing an error log on crash, but all Android apps already log to the built-in logger. You just need an app like [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) to view them.

Although verbose, you can usually filter by namespace (and see logs only related to your application). Eclipse does something similar with the built-in log viewer.

This is the only log viewer I used when I worked on my libGDX games.

Comment: My project is a desktop project though.

Comment: @GigaNova are you able to debug it with the Eclipse debugger?

Comment: ofcourse, but I'm running a compiler Jar file.

Comment: @GigaNova you should be able to set breakpoints and debug to the line that's terminating/failing. You should also be able to see some sort of exception (albeit maybe a runtime one) explaining why it's crashing.

Comment: Again, it works completely fine in Eclipse, It's the compiled Jar that doesn't work.

Comment: @GigaNova sounds like you need to add logging to your project in that case. Add some log statements and flush to the log file every write, and see what you get. There isn't a better solution that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

What I do to log errors is to surround my `render()` method with a `try` and `catch` block that catches the default `Exception` class. This writes a simple time-stamped log file. It can be implemented like this (Java 7+ Only):

```
@Override
public void render() {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss").format() + ".log") {
        //Code here
    } catch(Exception e) {
        writer.write("ERROR:\n");
        writer.write(e.getMessage());
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

You can run the program on the console using the `java -jar {jarname}.jar` command on the command line to see the error log.

Hope this helps! ~ Ammar Tarajia

P.S: On Windows, to navigate to the correct directory, just do the `cd` command then the folder. (Don't include the drive code!)